# Убрать клик за пределами ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

Пытаюсь убрать клик за пределами области ImageView. Думал проверять в OnTouch цвет пикселя, но он по какой-то причине все равно не ноль. Может кто сталкивался с таким[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    TheBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.first1);

    firstbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();



            int X = (int) event.getX();
            int Y = (int) event.getY();

            switch (eventPadTouch) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                    if (X >= 0 & Y >= 0 & X < TheBitmap.getWidth() & Y < TheBitmap.getHeight()) {

                        int b = TheBitmap.getPixel(X, Y);
                        if (b != 0) {


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "111111111111111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            firstbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.first2);


                        }

                        }
                    break;

                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    firstbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.first1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пошли по верному пути но вам нужно определять прозрачные пиксели **Color.TRANSPARENT** а не **null**, как вы написали.

```
if (Color.alpha(col) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
    //клик на место в картинке где нету цвета
}
```

Вот ссылка на похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669736/how-to-handle-custom-view-touch-event-only-on-opaquevisible-area

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Но как выяснилось у самой картинки есть еще и тень снизу, поэтому буду думать дальше)

Comment: Это конечно костыль но, можете сделать 2 одинаковые картинки только одна без тени (поверх первой), и только у второй сделать слушателя

Comment: Тоже об этом подумал. Может тень потом просто программно создать) Что-то придумаем. Был еще вариант создать просто зону клика по координатам, но пока еще не разобрался как.

Comment: Тень имеет какую-никакую прозрачность. Ее значение меняется от 0 до 255, транспонируется в 0f..1f. Соответственно, если Color.alpha(col)> .8f, то есть непрозрачность 80%, значит попали в картинку

Comment: Ну это уже совсем другая история. Спасибо, работает отлично, проверено. Оставил только это условие, чуть его видоизменив и красота. Тень не нужно вырезать)